# basic app.net implementation in ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, authentication, oauth

I've been trying to add basic app.net implementation into my ios app and having loads of trouble for reasons I cannot figure out.  All I really want to do is something simple like this:

http://hashpan.com/dev/help/appnet_client_side.htm

I have looked at the documentation and the various objective-c wrappers and really can't figure this out.  I find zero sample code out there as well which doesn't help.  Specifically I keep getting this when trying to setup an authorization screen:

http://cl.ly/0o032Z1H1E2y

And yes I have paid the dev fee so I have the rights to their api.  If anyone would be willing to spend a few minutes to help me that would be much appreciated as I'm not sure where to go for help with this.  Thanks,

rc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use one of the web flows.

Since it is an ios app, you will want to use either the password flow or the app.net Passport flow. The latter is probably what you really want to be doing. This allows users to authorize your app from the app.net Passport easily.

Password flow: http://developers.app.net/docs/authentication/flows/password/
app.net Passport auth: https://github.com/appdotnet/ADNLogin-SDK-iOS

Also, since you are on ios, you will be well served using ADNKit by @joeldev: https://github.com/joeldev/ADNKit

If you do indeed want to use the web flow, this error message probably implies that you have not setup the callback URL appropriately in the dev console for that app or that you are not escaping the characters in the callback URL properly inside of the authorization URL.